# predicting customers buying preference using Machine Learning

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis, k-means

I have set of transactions from a retail store. If I need to cluster the customers based on buying pattern I can do that using K-Means algorithm in Python.

How can I predict based on their earlier buying pattern, what are all products customers would be interested to buy in coming months?

I need to list products based on their choice of buying preference (high to low). What models or algorithm can be used for this?

Comment: This question is better suited for Cross Validated https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

[Association Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_rule_learning) is a text-book algorithm build for this use-case. You can also use [Collaborative Filtering](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/06/quick-guide-build-recommendation-engine-python/) can also be used to model the problem that you've described.

Here is a [Python implementation of Apriori Algorithm](http://aimotion.blogspot.in/2013/01/machine-learning-and-data-mining.html) which I believe would help you